# How to save output to a file simultaneously while python script is running, even with errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm crawling a site and saving the data in a text file. Every time I have an error in the last function, the whole output of the previous functions is gone. I want to save each one even when an error occurs.

I have tried using f.flush, os.fsync(f.fileno()), but they dont seem to work.

Lists is a dictionary. The dictionary values are functions that do a certain task of crawling. I want to save each loop and if an error happens, no data is lost and is saved from previous iterations.

```py
for i in lists:
    f.write('==================== [ ' + i + ' ] ====================\n')
    f.write(lists[i])
    f.write('\n')
```

I expect to be able to read each function output in the file while python is running and in an occasion of an error, the file is saved and the loop continues to the next function after the error without stopping.

EDIT: Adding all code:

I intentionally made the last function `alberti_ciper` without an h to see if the file will be saved or not when attempting all the mentioned methods.

EDIT2: removing source code for personal reasons.
Solved :)

Comment: Try using a try-except: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: @tituszban I did try using that, but its not writing to the file either way. The output runs fine if there is not error present, but in a case that one function presented an error, I dont want the output file to be empty

Comment: Put some writing to the file in the except!

Comment: @tituszban What do you mean put writing in the file? Every-time I write the script I have to empty the file if it exists so the output is unique based on the site information.

Comment: @rusu_ro1 This is my issue, I want to add more functions than this and if the function doesnt run I really dont want it to stop the execution and jump over or at leasssssst save the progress I had before and just close the script.. do you get me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code, your solution is simple:

```
f = open("output.txt", "w+")
text = input("[+] Enter Cipher/Hash/Encoded Text: ")
lists = {
    'Hash Decoder': "hash_decoder",
    'Ceaser Cipher': "cesar_cipher",
    'Affine Cipher': "affine_cipher",
    'Alberti Cipher': "alberti_ciper",
}
for i in lists:
    try:
        f.write('==================== [ ' + i + ' ] ====================\n')
        result = locals()[lists[i]](text)
        f.write(result)
        f.write('\n')
    except:
        f.write('Failed to run {}\n'.format(i))
    print("Finished {}".format(i))
```

EDIT: Update to handle misspelled function names, by using locals

Comment: when I use the code it shows to me that there is no function named alberti_ciper first and it exists the script, nothing happened, not output in file either.

Comment: Yes. Your code won't run, if you reference a function that doesn't exist. Fix the spelling, and try again.

Comment: @tituzban please read my problem up again, this is what I want exactly I want my program to jump over any error including broken functions, it works I wrote code before that does that exaclty, but why its not saving the progress in the file is my issue, I want it to save when running the code and when it reaches this fucntion it just closes or whaterver but the previous ones are saved!!

Comment: @OmarGhafri Right. Try the solution now. I've updated it, to reference your functions as strings, and look them up from locals.

Comment: This solved the first problem where it writes to the file even when an error is raised, but if I put another function underneath that works, it stops the output that the error one and stop script. I want it to output, jump over the error func and also at same time update in realtime to the file

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Are you saying, even though it has wrote `Failed to run...`, it didn't run the next one? Did you add the name of the function to the dict as a string?

Comment: I mean I made it like this     'Hash Decoder': "hash_decoder",
    'Ceaser Cipher': "cesar_cipher",
    'Affine Cipher': "affine_cipher",
    'Alberti Cipher': "alberti_ciper",
    'Affine Cipher': "affine_cipher",
so after the faulty ciper i want it to run affine cipher again just to make sure it jumps and continues but in the output file it stops at the faulty one and thats that.

Comment: That sounds really odd. The `try` should just swallow the error, and continue. Can you try the print I've added to the solution, and tell me what it prints?

Comment: You're using a dictionary. You have two of the same keys. Please fix that first, and try again

Comment: SupeeerrrBB!! I just need it to write on file when it executes each function if possible like seeing it live by pressing f5 for example and ill mark this as solved!

Comment: I've done that in the answer, but you should've been able to do that yourself!

Comment: No lol u didnt get me, your just saying finished in the terminal, that is already there by done, I meant live in the text document, like it appends the first function, then the next etc not all of them at once once the loop is finished is what i mean

Comment: Alright its fine I figured it out, I only added f.flush() and made instead of w+ to a+ and everything worked perfectly but you were the only one close to my answer so I top my hat to you for helping me through my 9 hours of frustration :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason, why you want to have an ability to run invalid code? You may want to use `try/except` to  handle cases when there was some errors in data or some sort of issues, you can't fix. When you trying to use undefined function, your code **must** raise an exception, so you can see it and then go and fix it. Your intention is wrong from the start in this case. If you intentionally changed name of the function, your code **must** not work. It is the correct behaviour

Comment: Becuase im gonna run this tool on around 3000 algorithms and most likely some will give an error like u need to input a number or maximum reached etc so i dont want my code to stop there or I dont want the file to be empty cause of that, you get my point :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
try:
    '''your code'''
except:
    continue
```

Comment: I have tried using continue and pass, but still there is no output and file is empty when reading it while python is running.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try `finally`

```
for i in lists:
   try:
       #do your work here
   except:
       # you may want to print a message or the exception 
   finally:
       #do your writing here
       f.write('==================== [ ' + i + ' ] ====================\n')
       f.write(lists[i])
       f.write('\n')
```

I think this might work.

Comment: It won't. The error will occur on the creation of the dictionary, not during saving

Comment: What I meant is, put anything that troubles you in a try block and the rest that should anyway happen, in the finally block.

Comment: If you look at the code provided, the error occurs when creating lists. By the time you're iterating over the results it's too late.

Comment: except:
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 0):

if you'll add

`f.flush()`

after

`f.write('\n')`

you'll be able to see the output in the file. Just don't forget, that not every text editor can dynamically reload file content. You may need to reopen file in your text editor.

If you have `tail` on your OS you can use this in terminal to see all changes in your file in realtime -

```
tail -f output.txt
```

Alternatively, you can open your file like this -

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w', buffering=1)
```

In this case you don't need to use `f.flush()`

**UPD:**

Also don't forget to close file when you done

Or you can use context manager

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    ...
```

It will close file for you after code under with is finished

Comment: I do f.close() at the end, didnt put it in the above code mentioned however, still even with buffering its and empty file, and when I view it with notepad++ and refresh it as the code runs its still empty.